# Given $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges and $a_n \neq -1$, show that $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges to a non-zero limit implies $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, products

I have been working on this problem for a while and cannot seem to make any progress without coming up with something wrong or hitting a dead end.

Here is what I have so far:

$ \prod (1+a_n) < \infty \implies   \sum a_n < \infty $: Similarly we ignore finitely many terms until $|a_n| \leq 1/2$ and we use the taylor series for the product. We have that 
$\prod 1+ a_n$ converging im plying that 
$\sum \log (1+a_n)$ converges to a nonzero limit since none of the factors are 0 as $a_n \neq -1$. We have that 
\begin{eqnarray}
|\sum \log(1+a_n) |  =| \sum (a_n-a_n^2/2 +\ldots) | \\ \geq | \sum (a_n-|a_n^2/2 +\ldots|) |  \geq \left| \sum a_n-|a_n|^2-|a_n|^3-\ldots \right| \\ = \left|\sum a_n-|a_n|^2(1+|a_n|+|a_n|^2+|a_n|^3+\ldots \right|
\end{eqnarray}
by the triangle inequality. Thus $\infty > |\sum \log(1+a_n) |  \geq \left|\sum a_n-2|a_n|^2 \right|$ from the previous part. Thus $\left|\sum a_n-2|a_n|^2 \right|$ is  convergent, and since $\sum|a_n|^2$ is absolutely convergent we can split the series (I don't really know if this is even true) and we have that partial sums $|\sum a_n|$ is bounded.

Any help would be appreciated! Also any good references for getting better at this kind of stuff would be great!!

Comment: This is an exercise in Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*, Chapter 5.

Comment: It may very well be, my teacher just put it on the problem set. He took problems from lots of different books without citing them, sometimes because he made minor changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every $|a|\lt\frac12$, $0\lt a-\log(1+a)\lt a^2$. Since $\sum\limits_n|a_n|^2$ converges, $|a_n|\lt\frac12$ for every $n$ large enough. Hence $\sum\limits_n\left(a_n-\log(1+a_n)\right)$ converges absolutely as soon as every $\log(1+a_n)$ exists.

This implies that $\sum\limits_na_n$ and $\sum\limits_n\log(1+a_n)$ both converge or both diverge. In particular, if $\sum\limits_n\log(1+a_n)$ converges, then $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges.

Comment: How do you know the part that $\sum |a_n - \log(1+a_n)|$ converges implies that $\sum a_n$ converging and $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ converging are equivalent? Also, thanks!

Comment: @jake: The triangle inequality ensures that
$$
\left|\sum a_n-\sum\log(1+a_n)\right|\le\sum\left|a_n-\log(1+a_n)\right|
$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true.  Consider e.g. $a_n = -1/(n+1)$, where $\prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n) = 1/(N+1) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Note that $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ converges to a nonzero limit iff $\sum_n \log (1 + a_n)$ converges, but you didn't say the limit had to be nonzero.

EDIT: @Didier points out the convention that part of the definition of "convergence" for an  infinite product is that the limit is nonzero.  This is not universal, however: see e.g. Rudin, "Real and Complex Analysis", sec. 15.1, or Conway, "Functions of One Complex Variable", sec. VII.5.

Comment: About the [convergence of infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I should have added that the product is converging to a non-zero limit.